# Remote desktop services deployment has vanished - Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services, rds

I've been working on a new solution recently which is basically a 2012 R2 RDS Farm. In a nutshell, the users RDP to the connection broker which in turn passes their connection out to one of the session hosts.

All was working fine until yesterday. There was a crash on one of the storage arrays and I ended up having to reboot everything.

Now that everything is back up, I log into the RDS server and instead of being able to see my collections and manage the deployment, I see this...

[image]

Now this has been working fine for a while now and I'm due to hand over to our customer for testing in the next couple of days... I could really do without having to rebuild this. Is there anything I can do to get my deployment details back?

Comment: Restore from backups if you have them.

Comment: I have backups of most of the VM's, but not all of them... which would I restore?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the connection broker or the session host? If it's the connection broker, that sucks but isnt that bad to rebuild depending on your environment. If it is the rdsh, great! You dont need to rebuild the entire server, only need to remove what bit of role for remote desktop is left installed, reboot and then reinstall the role. You should be able to point it to the connect broker easily with powershell and it will be as good as new.